# Nginx reverse proxy not load images files

Tags: nginx

I use Litespeed for Webserver and install nginx for reverse proxy!
Everything is fine but sometimes some of the images are not loaded!
With a refresh problem is resolved But it still happens!
this problem is for All website on server.
What to do?

Comment: Please provide additional information such as config file(s), log output, etc.

Comment: nginx is default config,
When I Deactive cache Everything is fine ! When active cache this This problem occurs.